# SwiftUI: Change VoiceOver name for TabView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

is it possible to change the name of a TabView from "tabbar" to another name?

If you first tap on an TabBar con VoiceOver says:
Tabbar - Info - tab 1 from 3.
if you click the other icons:
Einstellungen - gab 3 of 3.
After changing the focus away from tabbar and back VoiceOver starts again with Tabbar -

The accessibility modifier doesn't seems to works for me.

background: I'm developing an app for blind people and in German "täbbarr" sounds not really good...

```
 TabView() {
                
                InfoView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Info", systemImage: "info.circle")
                    }
                CategoryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Kategorien", systemImage: "list.dash")
                    }
                SettingsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Einstellungen", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
            }
            
        }
        .task()
        {
```

Comment: Can you share your code? To answer your question, yes, but we need to know specifics.

Comment: I used Accessibility Inspector on a TabView, and it never read "Tab Bar" at all. It hit each individual tab, but not the tab bar itself.

Comment: attached the code - pretty simple and added a little bit more explanation